# Converting truth tables to boolean expressions

Tags: list-manipulation, boolean-computation

I have a truth table for a Boolean expression represented like this

```
table={{0, 0, 0, 0} -> 0, {0, 0, 0, 1} -> 0, {0, 0, 1, 0} -> 
0, {0, 0, 1, 1} -> 0, {0, 1, 0, 0} -> 0, {0, 1, 0, 1} -> 
0, {0, 1, 1, 0} -> 0, {0, 1, 1, 1} -> 1, {1, 0, 0, 0} -> 
1, {1, 0, 0, 1} -> 1, {1, 0, 1, 0} -> 1, {1, 0, 1, 1} -> 
1, {1, 1, 0, 0} -> 1, {1, 1, 0, 1} -> 1, {1, 1, 1, 0} -> 
1, {1, 1, 1, 1} -> 0}
```

(all on one line)

The table contains the values I want at the output given y4,y3,y2,y1 at the input, i.e.

```
{y4,y3,y2,y1} -> desiredOutput
```

What is the best way to transform this data into a form that can be then processed in terms of y with functions such as BooleanMinimize?

Comment: It is not completely clear what your result should be. When you want to make a function out of your `table`, you could do it as follows: `(func[#1] = #2) & @@@ table;` and then you can easily call `func[{1, 0, 1, 0}]`. Does that help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
BooleanMinimize[BooleanFunction[table]]

(*  (#1 && ! #2) || (#1 && ! #3) || (#1 && ! #4) || (! #1 && #2 && #3 &&  #4) & *)
```

Note in the documentation how 1/0 vs True/False are treated here, massage as needed.

Quick verification:

```
bf = BooleanFunction[table];

Rule @@@ Transpose[{table[[All, 1]], 
    bf[Sequence @@ #] & /@ table[[All, 1]] // Boole}];

% == table

(* True *)
```

Comment: BooleanFunction is exactly what I was looking for. After reading the documentation I see that BooleanFunction[table, {y4, y3, y2, y1}] will name the variables as desired.